How to correlate HTTP request to its corresponding response with Apache Flink?
I'm looking for the best practice to correlate requests and their corresponding responses in an Apache Flink stream processing job. The key attributes of the problem are:
Conditions:
Each request and response pair has a unique flowid associated with them.
The order of requests and responses is not guaranteed. However, the response must arrive within 30 seconds of the request.
Current Implementation:
Our current approach involves manually implementing a correlation processor where we:
Key the stream by flowid to form a keyed stream.
For each keyed stream, we store the state of the first arriving packet and wait for the second packet to arrive. We use ValueState in this case and set its ttl to 30s.
Once the second packet arrives, we combine and emit the pair, and clear the state.
Issues with Current Implementation:
The downside of our implementation is that:
We manage the state ourselves, which might not be optimized.
The memory usage is excessive and becomes unacceptable as the volume scales.
Questions:
Is there a mature implementation available for performing this kind of correlation?
Are there any recommendations for a more efficient way to correlate requests and responses in Flink, especially with constraints like a 30-second window?
Additional Information:
We are working with Flink version 1.13.0.
I'm seeking advice on whether there are any optimized methods or existing Flink capabilities that could help streamline our current approach. Any pointers, libraries, or specific strategies would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your insights!

KeyedCoProcessFunction is your friend. It not just allows you to store state but also gives you access to TimeService which you can trigger 30 secs after 1st packet arrives.
Here's an example that may help.
Also, one important thing: KeyedCoProcessFunction works on keyed streams. Flink distributes keys to slots and based on how you are setting up your env, those keys may end up on different task managers effectively distributing your state.

Many thanks Boss! However, I noted that CoProcessFunction is used for different inputs. In this case, we have both requests and responses in the same source, which makes it incompatible with CoProcessFunction, isn't it?

I read your current implementation again. You said you have a keyed streams based on flowid. Separating request/response based on flowid is good first step. Then you use KeyedCoProcessFunction where process1 will process requests and process2 will process response.

I will try with KeyedCoProcessFunction. Thanks for your advice!
